# In the state of Arizona, how do funeral homes create a new death certificate and register it?

Tags: death

My question pertains to law in the United States.

My mother died 2 months ago.

The police came and took her body away.

The medical examiner's office did an autopsy, etc...

I have paid the state of Arizona more than $150 for copies of death certificates.

I first ordered a certificate almost one month ago.

The state of Arizona will not give me the death certificates.

Initially, the state told me that all of the paper-work was correctly filed.

Recently, the state told me that the death must be "*registered*" by a funeral home before any death-certificates can be issued.

There is ***no*** funeral home. There will never be a funeral home.

I was the one responsible for collecting my mother's remains and burying her.

Arizona Law says something like:

> Within seven calendar days after receiving possession of human remains, the responsible person who takes possession of the human remains shall:
>
> 1. Obtain and complete the information, including the social security number of the decedent, on the death certificate required pursuant to this chapter and rules adopted pursuant to this chapter.
> 2. Provide on the death certificate the name and address of the person completing the death certificate.
> 3. Submit the death certificate for registration to a local registrar, a deputy local registrar or the state registrar.  The funeral establishment or responsible person may submit the death certificate by electronic means in the format prescribed by the state registrar.

However, I do not know what a certificate of death looks like.
I also do not know what information is required on the certificate.

If you were a funeral home in Arizona, how would you make one?
What information would be on it?

Comment: Can you provide the source of your quoted content please? If possible provide a direct link.